# I am facing issue of HTTP ERROR 500 when i try ro login or just look on my website

Tags: php, wordpress, http

I am using free hosting for my practice , i am facing now the problem of HTTP ERROR 500 and I can't even access to my dashboard , what should I do.
https://itsosmos.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Infinit redirects (this might have happened when you tried to change site  link or something)
Try replacing your .htaccess with a default wordpress htaccess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

if there is a Memory limit use :

```
    php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

if this doesnt work, try deleting the recent plugin/theme you've installed from your database .
Check your error log for more.